# Porting PHP API over to Parse

Tags: api, parse-platform

I am a PHP dev looking to port my API over to the Parse platform.

Am I right in thinking that you only need cloud code for complex operations? For example, consider the following methods:

```
// Simple function to fetch a user by id
function getUser($userid) {
    return (SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=$userid LIMIT 1) 
}

// another simple function, fetches all of a user's allergies (by their user id)
function getAllergies($userid) {
    return (SELECT * FROM allergies WHERE userid=$userid) 
}

// Creates a script (story?) about the user using their user id
// Uses their name and allergies to create the story
function getScript($userid) {
    $user = getUser($userid)
    $allergies = getAllergies($userid).
    return "My name is {$user->getName()}. I am allergic to {$allergies}" 
}
```

Would I need to implement getUser()/getAllergies() endpoints in Cloud Code? Or can I simply use Parse.Query("User")... thus leaving me with only the getScript() endpoint to implement in cloud code?

Comment: I try and do as much as possible, and securely, in Cloud Code, but it's really up to you.  Feel free to shoot me an email at fosco@parse.com regarding parse and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud code is for computation heavy operations that should not be performed on the client, i.e. handling a large dataset.

It is also for performing beforeSave/afterSave and similar hooks.

In your example, providing you have set up a reasonable data model, none of the operations require cloud code.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds reasonable. I tend to put simply queries that will most likely not change on the client side, but it all depends on your scenario. When developing mobile apps I tend to put a lot of code in cloud code. I've found that it speeds up my development cycle. For example, if someone finds a bug and it's in cloud code, make the fix, run parse deploy, done! The change is available to all mobile environments instantly!!! If that same code is in my mobile app, it really sucks, cause now I have to fix the bug, rebuild, push it to the app store/google play, wait x number of days for it to be approved, have the users download it... you see where I'm going here.

Take for example your 
    SELECT * FROM allergies WHERE userid=$userid query.

Even though this is a simple query, what if you want to sort it? maybe add some additional filtering?

These are the kinds of things I think of when deciding where to put the code. Hope this helps!

As a side note, I have also found cloud code very handy when needing to add extra security to my apps.